# There's a Jack Reacher here to see you

Tags: indefinite-article

> - Rodin: So... how do we find this Reacher?
> - Emerson: Obviously, you don't find this guy unless he wants to be found.
> - Secretary: Excuse me, sir. There's **a** Jack Reacher here to see you.

Can we use indefinite articles (a) with people names? Is it mistake? or informal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the phrase is "a person whose name is X".

It can be used in a number situations. For example:

a hotel lobby:

> Is there a Tom Smith here?
>   -- I'm Tom Smith.
>   A fax has come in for you at the hotel desk. It's marked Urgent.

or at the check-in desk in a high-rise office building:

> There's a Mike Jones here to see Mr. Johnson. He says he has an appointment.

or a customer service agent speaking to his supervisor:

> The person on the phone said she called yesterday and spoke with a Ms. Green about this same issue, who told him that it had been resolved. Do we have a Ms. Green working here?

Answer (score 1):

They can be used to introduce someone for an appointment:

> There's a Colonel Mustard here to see you.
>
> There's a Mister Jones here to see you.

It can also be used to imply that the person is not worthy of being referred to as a human, but that's not the use in this Lee Child novel.